# Using expand in pipe replaces values

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, expand

I currently have a service where i fetch some templates with help of expand to display them in the view. The idea is to keep fetching untill i have everything.

However, when i pipe the expand it replaces the values instead of adding them, how do i solve this?

Example:

```
templates$: Observable<Template[]>;
let count = 0;

this.templates$ = this.templateService.getTemplates(0, 5).pipe(
      expand(result => {
        count += result.length;
        if (result.length === 5) {
          return this.templateService.getTemplates(count, 5);
        } else {
          return empty();
        }
      })
    );
```

Comment: Which version of RxJs ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to add a `reduce` operator after the `expand`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`expand` does not replace value, it rather emits each time you receive the templates in groups of five. In your view, if you use `template$ | async`, you'll only see the last result.

To collect all templates, you can use `scan` operator.

```
templates$: Observable<Template[]>;
let count = 0;

this.templates$ = this.templateService.getTemplates(0, 5).pipe(
      expand(result => {
        count += result.length;
        if (result.length === 5) {
          return this.templateService.getTemplates(count, 5);
        } else {
          return empty();
        }
      }),
      scan((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr))
    );
```

You could also use `reduce` operator the same way, if you don't want to show intermediate results.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i was looking for.